# Live example of GWT

Tags: gwt

I am looking for some interactive sites build in GWT. I require this for setting the benchmark for my project and to know the extent that how good applications can be made using GWT.Please suggest me some URLs of the existing websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list available at http://www.gwtproject.org/examples.html, including some real-world examples.

Some of the GWT UI widgets are demonstrated at http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html.

Comment: Thanks I was looking exactly for such thing...